# Call a COM DLL dynamically

Tags: visual-c++, dynamic, dll, com, vb6

I have an application in VC++ which needs to execute a function provided to it (function name entered in a text box) from a COM DLL (file name provided in another text box).

I have seen code for loading a Win32 library using `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.

How can this be done for a COM DLL file (created in Visual Basic 6.0)? Is there a link where I can get more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the component that you're calling supports [`IDispatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221608.aspx) (which is quite likely if it was created in VB), you can use late binding to call COM interface methods dynamically.

For example:

```
IDispatch *pDispatch;
// Assumes pUnknown is IUnknown pointer to component that you want to call.
HRESULT hr = pUnknown->QueryInterface(IID_IDispatch, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&pDispatch));
if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    DISPID dispid;
    // Assumes sMethodName is BSTR containing name of method that you want to call.
    hr = pDispatch->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &sMethodName, 1, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &dispid);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Assumes that the method takes zero arguments.
        VARIANT vEmpty;
        vEmpty.vt = VT_EMPTY;
        DISPPARAMS dp = { &vt, 0, 0, 0 };
        hr = pDispatch->Invoke(dispid, IID_INULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, &dp, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    pDispatch->Release();
}
```

This example fetches the [`DISPID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221242.aspx) of the named method from [`IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221306.aspx), then calls that method by passing the `DISPID` to [`IDispatch::Invoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221479.aspx).

For the sake of clarity, I've assumed that there are no arguments to the method you want to call, but you can modify the [`DISPPARAMS` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221416.aspx) that is passed to `Invoke()` if there are.